# How do I make a slideshow button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

i m trying to make a lightbox for images. I have the next and previous button and they are working. now i m trying to make slideshow button using my existing code...is this possible to make slideshow play and pause buttons using my code...here is my code...

```
var current_index = 0 // Our current index and total_images is the array variable containing images path
    function Next() // Call to go to the next image
    {
        // If we're at the last index, go to zero, else go to the next index
        current_index = (current_index === (total_images.length - 1) ? 0 : current_index + 1);
        UpdateImage(); // Call update
    }

    function Previous() // Call to go to the previous image
    {
        // If we're at the first index (0), go to the last, otherwise go to the previous index
        current_index = (current_index === 0 ? (total_images.length - 1) : current_index - 1);
        UpdateImage(); // Call update
    }

    function UpdateImage() // Call to update the image element
    {
        document.getElementById('imgFull').src = total_images[current_index]; // Self explaining
    }function Play()
    {
        var runSlideShow = setInterval(Next, 3000);
    }
    function Stop()
    {
        window.clearInterval(runSlideShow);
    }
```

Comment: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ this is useful

Comment: its not useful...do u have any other way..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval and call Next() Function and use clearInterval to pause the slideshow.

```
var runSlideShow = setInterval(Next, 3000);
clearInterval(runSlideShow);
```

Comment: runslideshow works but when i call clearInterval on pause button click it not stops the slideshow

Comment: Can you provide us a jsfiddle? So we can see where is the problem?

Comment: i have added two new function playy and stop in my above code please take a look there...

Comment: var runSlideShow put it on top so it can be global like you have done with current_index variable. Try that and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Could u please tell me how can add fadeout() when image changes and fadeIn() when next image appears...

Comment: $( "#imgFull" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
     document.getElementById('imgFull').src = total_images[current_index]; $( "#imgFull" ).fadeIn();
  }); Something like that. Put it inside UpdateImage. You'll need jQuery.

Comment: This will be your UpdateImage function

Answer (score 0):

Use window.setInterval calling the next method. Using this you can keep calling the next every 5 seconds say.

```
var intervalSlide = window.setInterval(Next,5000);
window.clearInterval(intervalSlide);
```

You can then call clearInterval when you reach the end.

You will need to declare you setInterval outside you function so you have the use to clear at the end.

Comment: intevalSlide works but when i call window.clearInterval(intervalSlide); on pause button click it not stops the slideshow

Comment: Make sure your intervalSlide is created in the context, as a global.                              see this link for example   http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval

Comment: Also just noticed I missed typed interval im the var declaration. I have updated the example